# open a file with NERDTree without creating a new split

Tags: vim

I like NERDTree but I do not want a new split if I open a new file. I just want to reuse the current window. Is this possible ?

Comment: The whole purpose of NERDTree is to provide a *side-panel* and all its commands are designed around that idea. The built-in netrw, on the other side, does what you want and more.

Comment: Have you tried opening a `netrw` window with `:E` instead of NERDTree? Might be preferable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

My NERDTree help says that I should press 'o',  or double-click to "open in prev window" and it works.

Comment: `set hidden` will help in this case

Comment: I have the same problem. Where can I add "set hidden"? In my .vimrc?

Comment: Yes, you can set it in your .vimrc.